# datetime value convert on variable save

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am trying to save a date as an octopus variable
The date format is like 2019-05-26T00:00:00+00:00
But while trying to save this octopus is automatically converting it into 05/25/2014 20:00:00 this formart.

Please suggest any way to save the variable in the original(i.e. 2019-05-26T00:00:00+00:00) format

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to format the datetime correctly like this:

"#{Time | Filter "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:ss"}"